How to extract page numbers when using Azure Form Recognizer with DOCX files?
I am currently using Azure Form Recognizer to process DOCX files, but I've encountered an issue that I need help with. Unlike when I process PDF files, where I can extract text along with the corresponding page numbers, I am unable to obtain page numbers when working with DOCX files.
Problem Details:

File Type: DOCX
Functionality Needed: Extract text with associated page numbers.
Current Behavior: When I pass a DOCX file to Azure Form Recognizer, I only get the text without any page number information.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using to extract text from the DOCX file:
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
import os

# Function to initialize the Document Analysis Client
def initialize_client():
    # Replace these with your Form Recognizer resource endpoint and API key
    endpoint = os.environ.get("DI_Endpoint")  # Set your endpoint in environment variable
    api_key = os.environ.get("DI_Key")        # Set your API key in environment variable

    # Initialize the Azure Form Recognizer client
    client = DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(api_key))
    return client

# Function to extract text from a docx file using Azure Form Recognizer
def extract_text_from_docx(client, docx_path):
    try:
        # Check if the file is indeed a .docx file
        if not docx_path.lower().endswith('.docx'):
            raise ValueError("The provided file is not a .docx file.")

        # Open the docx file in binary mode
        with open(docx_path, "rb") as docx_file:
            print("Sending the following file for analysis:", docx_path)
            # Start analyzing the docx with the prebuilt document model
            poller = client.begin_analyze_document("prebuilt-document", document=docx_file)
            result = poller.result()

            # Extract and print text from each page
            for page in result.pages:
                print(f"----Analyzing layout from page #{page.page_number}----")
                for line in page.lines:
                    print(line.content)  # Print each line's text content

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error analyzing document: {e}")

# Main function to run the script
def main():
    client = initialize_client()
    docx_path = input("Please enter the path to your .docx file: ")
    
    # Check if the provided path is a valid file
    if os.path.isfile(docx_path) and docx_path.lower().endswith('.docx'):
        extract_text_from_docx(client, docx_path)
    else:
        print("Invalid file path or file format. Please provide a valid .docx file.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Error:
Error analyzing document: (InvalidRequest) Invalid request.
Code: InvalidRequest
Message: Invalid request.
Inner error: {                                 
    "code": "InvalidContent",
    "message": "The file is corrupted or format is unsupported. Refer to documentation for the list of supported formats."
}

File which is used : Docx_File
Constraints:

I do not want to convert my DOCX files into PDF format.
I do not want to use any hidden characters or preprocessing techniques in the file.

What I've Tried:

I have checked the documentation for Azure Form Recognizer to confirm that page number extraction works for PDFs but not for DOCX files.
I have also explored using Azure Cognitive Services and other APIs, but they do not meet my requirements without converting to PDF.

Expected Outcome:
I am looking for a way to extract text from DOCX files along with the page numbers, similar to the behavior with PDF files, without altering the DOCX file or changing its format.
Note:
I want to limit myself to Azure Form Recognizer only

Aside from any trouble you're having with Azure, page numbering is just not reliably present in a DOCX file.  See How to access OpenXML content by page number? and Can't get the pages count from a word document with OpenXml.
